# Oracle SQL Partitions and Rank

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to be able to group data by effective dates for the most current project for employees, including department, and manager they work for. Here is a sample of the data.

**PROJ_TBL**

```
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | EFF_DATE | EMPL_PROJECT   |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| P1441       | 05/21/11 | IMC            |
| P1441       | 09/12/12 | BEEB           |
| P1441       | 09/23/12 | PRUD_FIN_SALES |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

**EMPLOYEE_TBL**

```
+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | PROJECT_MBR  | DEPT_NM | EFF_DATE |
+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| P1441       | BEN DEENEY   | ACCNT   | 02/09/08 |
| P1566       | LAURA FIELDS | ACCNT   | 05/03/10 |
| P2155       | PAUL DAVEY   | ACCNT   | 10/03/10 |
| P1441       | BEN DEENEY   | SALES   | 07/19/12 |
+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

**EMP_DPT_TBL**

```
+-------------+---------------+---------+----------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER       | DEPT_NM | EFF_DATE |
+-------------+---------------+---------+----------+
| P1441       | BOB PAISLEY   | ACCNT   | 02/09/08 |
| P1441       | LINDA HARDY   | SALES   | 07/19/12 |
+-------------+---------------+---------+----------+
```

I'm not very familiar with the use of partitions.  I want to be able to use it to combine the information to get the current data for `EMPLOYEE_ID` `P1441`. The desired output is :

```
+-------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | DEPT_NM | MANAGER      | PROJECT        |
+-------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| P1441       | SALES   | LINDA HARDY  | PRUD_FIN_SALES |
+-------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
```

I am able to get the correct current records for the individual tables but combining the results to generate what I want is problematic.  Here are the queries...

```
-- Current Project
SELECT EMPL_PROJECT,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       EFF_DT
FROM   ( SELECT EMPL_PROJECT,
                EMPLOYEE_ID,
                EFF_DT,
                RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID
                              ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC) AS rk1
        FROM    PROJ_TBL ) t
WHERE  rk1 = 1

-- Current Department
SELECT DEPT_NM,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       EFF_DT
FROM   ( SELECT DEPT_NM,
                EMPLOYEE_ID,
                EFF_DT,
                RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID
                              ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC ) AS rk2 
         FROM   EMPLOYEE_TBL ) t
WHERE  rk2 = 1

-- Current Manager
SELECT MANAGER,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       EFF_DT
FROM   ( SELECT MANAGER,
                EMPLOYEE_ID,
                EFF_DT,
                RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID
                              ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC ) AS rk3
         FROM   EMP_DPT_TBL ) t
WHERE  rk3 = 1
```

How can I combine these into one query using the `EMPLOYEE_ID` to generate the report?

Comment: Entirely unrelated to your question, but why do you, in the `employee_tbl`, store both the employee's ID and his or her name? The better (normalized) design is to have a different table with the employee ID as primary key (so, no duplicates!) and for each ID, the employee's name. That would in fact be called an "employee_tbl". Then what you show as your second table is a historical table of assignments of employees to different departments; this historical table should have only employee ID's, not names - and the same for departments (include only dept ID and have a separate DEPARTMENTS_TBL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  EMPLOYEE_ID
  ,first_value(dept.dept_nm) over (partition by dept.employee_id order by dept.eff_date desc) as DEPT_NM
  ,first_value(dept.manager) over (partition by dept.employee_id order by dept.eff_date desc) as MANAGER
  ,first_value(proj.EMPL_PROJECT) over (partition by proj.employee_id order by proj.eff_date desc) as PROJECT
FROM
  EMPLOYEE_TBL emp
  INNER JOIN PROJ_TBL proj ON emp.EMPLOYEE_ID = proj.EMPLOYEE_ID
  INNER JOIN EMP_DPT_TBL dept on emp.EMPLOYEE_ID = dept.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: My bad, it seems to be working let me do a few more checks